# Dynamically Create Bookmarks with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to dynamically add bookmarks into a Word file from Excel based on the length of a dynamically allocated array. I then want to change the text at each bookmark to the corresponding value in the array.

My reason for doing this rather than just using static bookmarks is the program doesn't know how long the array will be or what data will be included until it runs. My thought process was to have one 'anchor' bookmark that the first iteration will use and then add bookmarks as needed after the original/previous one.

What I have below uses prevRange.End but it faults because this isn't a range, but I felt that it would get my point across as to what I was attempting to do.

I would use Bookmarks.InsertAfter except that I am trying to create a bullet list in Word and this messes with the formatting and reverses the order of the list.

I would prefer to find a way to dynamically do this rather than do a brute force method with a large amount of bookmarks and then delete the ones I don't need.

wrdRange, prevRange, and wrdDoc are defined elsewhere in the program.

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim CountM As Integer
Count = 1

Do While Clar(Count) <> ""       'Clar() is a dynamically allocated 1D array containing text
CountM = Count - 1
PrevBmarkName = "Clar" & CountM
BmarkName = "Clar" & Count      'Only bookmark in Word document to start with is Clar1
BmarkText = Clar(Count)

If Count <> 1 Then
    Set prevRange = wrdDoc.Bookmarks(PrevBmarkName).Range
    wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="BmarkName", Range:=prevRange.End 'Faults here because prevRange.end isn't a range
    Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Bookmarks(BmarkName).Range
    If Clar(Count + 1) = "" Then   'Used for the end of the list so there isn't a floating bullet point
        wrdRange.Text = BmarkText
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=BmarkName, Range:=wrdRange
    Else
        wrdRange.Text = BmarkText & vbNewLine
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=BmarkName, Range:=wrdRange
    End If
Else         'Functions normally through the first iteration, replaces Clar1 with clar(1) text
    Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Bookmarks(BmarkName).Range
    wrdRange.Text = BmarkText & vbNewLine
    wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=BmarkName, Range:=wrdRange
End If

Count = Count + 1
CountM = CountM + 1
Loop
```

Comment: A `Bookmark` object has an `End` property - have you tried using this for the insertion point instead of `Range.End`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SetRange` method as per below:

```
    Set prevRange = wrdDoc.Bookmarks(PrevBmarkName).Range
    Set newRange = prevRange   'Have to set the range to something initially
    newRange.SetRange prevRange.End, prevRange.End
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "BmarkName", newRange
```

Comment: @Alex I saw your comment right before I hit the sack last night but this morning its gone. Did you get everything sorted?

Comment: Yes I was, but I had to rethink how I was creating the list due to formatting. I had to create the list and then do the formatting in reverse order because the bookmark also contained the last character of the previous line.
        `Set newRange = prevRange
        newRange.SetRange prevRange.End, prevRange.End
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "BmarkName", newRange
        newRange.Text = vbNewLine & BmarkText
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=BmarkName, Range:=newRange`    And then did the formatting elsewhere